# How to add links into php dynamically generated table to return values?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['mf_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I want to make the Manufacturer column clickable and return the value of the corresponding `mf_id` value to another page

Comment: My bad, manufacturer column :)
edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['mf_id']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"yourlink.php?mf_id=" . htmlspecialchars($row['mf_id']) . "\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

So when you click the link you will be brought to the page "yourlink.php".
If you want the value that was in $row['mf_id'] do this:

```
$mf_id = $_GET['mf_id']
```

$mf_id will now hold the value that was passed to the page.

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` if you don't want reserved characters erroneously ending up in your HTML.

Comment: Can you explain where this would be used? Like this? htmlspecialchars($row['mf_id'])

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If you know that the ID is just going to be numeric, it isn't a big deal.  But, if you have variable data that may contain characters such as `"` or `<`, then you need to use `htmlspecialchars()`.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll include it now

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed what I was looking for. Though how do I make it so that each link returns the corresponding mf_id value to my page? I only know how to do so through forms. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited the above. Look at the second part

Answer (score 2):

You can use your variables in any context you want, including anchor tags:

```
echo '<td><a href="', htmlspecialchars('yourpage.php?mf_id=' . $row['mf_id']), '">',
    htmlspecialchars($row['mf_id']), '</a></td>';
```

If you want to link the entire row, you will need a JavaScript click handler.  Otherwise, simple anchor tags will do what you want.